# How to show the UWP ShellBackButton as a button in Template10?

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I need to show the UWP ShellBackButton as a button in my user control in Template10.

The ShellBackButton is the back button on top left in the application but I need to show this as a button in the main screen so the user can click on it.

I have researched this, but could not find how to do this.

There a property in `App.xaml.cs` to show the button on top left, that is `ShowShellBackButton` and I want to have this as a button in my user control view.

Answer (score 0):

Template10 provides a navigation service through the Bootstrapper (and surfaces it through the ViewModelBase.NavigationService property) that you can use to handle backwards navigation in your button:

`if ( NavigationService.CanGoBack )
    NavigationService.GoBack();`

See https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Bootstrapper#navigation-service for more details about INavigationService and the Bootstrapper.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the reply. I did follow the example there,https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Controls#navigation , but still could not show the back button on canvas. I wonder you can direct me to more specific example. I just wanted to show the back button on canvas, not on the top left corner. Thank you.

Comment: The back button in the title bar is implemented through a template, so you cannot move it from the title bar. Your best bet is to add a button control to your canvas, and to style the button to look however you want it to. That button should call the INavigationService.GoBack() method.

Comment: Thanks for the info Jim. Actually Template10 has something similar to that back button on canvas, and the navigation will be handled by Template10 automagically, based on the sample code here <pre><Page x:Class="Controls.MainPage"
      xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls">

    <controls:PageHeader Frame="{x:Bind Frame}" 
        BackButtonVisibility="Visible"
        Text="Detail" />

</Page></pre>  The only problem is that when I tested, it does not work. I navigated away to page 2 but the back button is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

As from the comments, i thought it's completely irrelevant to keep the old answer. So The updated answer is below:

### The Control

This is just a basic dummy version of the control and you will need to add visual states and other resources, assets and custom styles but the skeleton would look like below:

**The C#**

```
public sealed class MyDummyControl : Control
{

    #region fields
    private const string primaryIconName = "PrimaryIcon";
    #endregion fields

    #region UIElements
    private AppBarButton PrimaryIcon;
    #endregion UIElements

    #region Events

    public event Action PrimaryButtonClicked;

    #endregion Events

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        PrimaryIcon = this.GetTemplateChild(primaryIconName) as AppBarButton;

        //in cases with c# versions lower than 6.0
        //consider replacing the null conditional check(?) with the tradional
        //if(BackRequested!=null) and 
        //the lambda's and annonymous methods with { } and methodName()
        if (PrimaryIcon != null)
            PrimaryIcon.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                PrimaryButtonClicked?.Invoke();
            };

    }

    public MyDummyControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyDummyControl);
    }

    #region Dependancy Properties


    public UIElement HeaderContent
    {
        get { return (UIElement)GetValue(HeaderContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderContentProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderContent", typeof(UIElement), typeof(MyDummyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    public bool IsPrimaryIconCompact
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPrimaryIconCompactProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsPrimaryIconCompactProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsPrimaryIconCompact.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPrimaryIconCompactProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsPrimaryIconCompact", typeof(bool), typeof(MyDummyControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));




    public UIElement Content
    {
        get { return (UIElement)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Content.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(UIElement), typeof(MyDummyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    public SolidColorBrush HeaderBackground
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(HeaderBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderBackground.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderBackground", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(MyDummyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Gray)));




    public SymbolIcon Icon
    {
        get { return (SymbolIcon)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Icon.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(SymbolIcon), typeof(MyDummyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Cancel)));



    public string IconLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(IconLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconLabelProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IconLabel.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconLabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconLabel", typeof(string), typeof(MyDummyControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    #endregion Dependancy Properties


}
```

Once created the Control, now you need to add the default style to it:
**The Resource Dictionary**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Controls="using:ShellBackButtonDummy.Controls">

<Style TargetType="Controls:MyDummyControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Controls:MyDummyControl">
                <Grid x:Name="layoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" >

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Name="HeaderBanner" Background="{TemplateBinding HeaderBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderContent}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <AppBarButton x:Name="PrimaryIcon" Icon="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Label="{TemplateBinding IconLabel}" IsCompact="{TemplateBinding IsPrimaryIconCompact}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"/>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The above are the two necessary things required for the control to function properly.

Later on you can edit the resource dictionary to personalize the control and once you have it all figured out you can freeze it and when you use it in other apps, you can simply override the default style instead of manually changing the resource dictionary each time.

I hope this helps. I've uploaded a copy of a template 10 version of the solution on  [GitGub](https://github.com/ImCarrot/ShellBackButtonSample)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aditya, I did try the example there, especially at the Overriding built-in behavior section. When I implement this <Page x:Class="Controls.MainPage"
      xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls">

    <controls:PageHeader Frame="{x:Bind Frame}" 
        BackButtonVisibility="Visible"
        Text="Detail" />

</Page> and navigate to the second page, the back button is not showing at all. I wonder if there is something missing?

Comment: Can you do a quick check for me, change the visibility and then restart the app. Don't redeploy just restart and check if it worked. Because if it does then I know where the issue is. Else I'll work up a quick demo

Comment: thanks again for the quick reply. I did try couple times changing the visibility property and still it is not showing the back button. A quick demo will be really helpful. I have been having this issue for couple days now. Thank you much.

Comment: Great. I'll work up a quick demo. it won't even take long. Can you please share what exactly are you trying to do? like you mentioned user control. and you mentioned Navigation. Can you please elaborate. or if you want you can share a demo of the issue causing code and I can fix it. either is okay

Comment: I have a requirement to show a back button, something similar with the one from Template10 example above. I tried to put them into a user control, this button is just to handle the back navigation. It does not need to be a user control btw, it just need to update the page to the previous screen when the back button is clicked. Again thank you.

Comment: Oh so basically you opened up a user control to show some UI and now you need a back button on the user control to hide the User control and show the main frame. Did I get it right? If I did, then there are other easy ways too to implement such a thing

Comment: No not really, it just a back button to take you to the previous screen. Something similar with the ShellBackButton in the title bar. For some reasons the customer does not want to have that title bar to show, thus I need to create another button, inside the screen so that when the user clicks on that button, it will give you the previous screen something like navigating back. Thank you.

Comment: I am working on a demo as we speak. So do you want to go back on the navigation frame or do you want to hide the user control. If you want to go back on the navigation frame I wonder why are you using a user control instead of a page. I am so sorry for asking too many questions, I just want to provide with the demo tailored for your use case scenario so that your effort in integration is almost negligible

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I appreciate that. A page is fine, at first I was thinking about a user control so that I can easily port it out for other projects. I will need to have the navigation "button" visible at all time so the user can press it again to go back to the previous screens. thank you again for your help.

Comment: Okay if I may, so from your portability stand point it would not be recommended to have a backbutton on a user control that is talking to template 10 navigation service as you might want to use the same in projects that may not use template 10 or maybe not even be UWP, windows phone 8.1 maybe. So to provide portability, you must use a control instead of a user control or a page and that control would have content and a default style along with a customisable button that when pressed, fired up an event called maybe back_requested which the parent view can subscribe to

Comment: and then handle the back request based on the platform over which it's being used. Would you want me to provide a demo of this control instead?

Comment: Yes, that will be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Great. I'll work on a quick control. I would provide a nifty control but you'll have to modify the style and put in your own Visual States.

Comment: Sounds good! the feature to go back to the previous screens is the key here btw. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay, I got caught up in things. As promised, I've updated my answer to provide insights on the control we've been talking about also I have uploaded the solution to GitHub if you want to download it and Run it yourself. I hope it helps. Do let me know if I missed out something.

Comment: Hi Aditya, thank you for the time to make the sample. The problem is that the back button needs to be in the content area, next to word "MainPage" or "Setting Page" in the page header section. I was able to show the back button in the title bar but the customer does not want it to be here and would like to hide the title bar completely. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the UI desired? UI tweaking won't even take seconds. That being said, you can open up blend and then click on the control and then modify the default style of the control to get the desired outlook. Anyhow share a screenshot so that we can quickly resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got this working. Here is the solution for future reference, if you ever stuck in this situation.

The following will need to be inside your ViewModel inheriting the ViewModelBase in Template10.

```
var nav = Template10.Common.WindowWrapper.Current().NavigationServices.FirstOrDefault();
        var frame = nav.Frame;
        if (frame.CanGoBack)
            frame.GoBack();
```

You can also make it so that the back button is visible or not by using the CanGoBack property.

Comment: Template10.Mvvm.ViewModelBase contains a reference to NavigationService of INavigationService that you can use.